# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'aop:config'

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, configuration

I'm a novice working through my first JAVA Spring application largely based example in the Spring in Action 4th Edition by Craig Wall and I'm stuck on this error ...

Error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: 
Line 20 in XML document from class path resource [Knights.xml] is invalid;
nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 20;
columnNumber: 14; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'aop:config'.
```

My application works as I would expect without the `<aop:config>` tag in the XML file.

The XML file in question ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:aop="http://springframework.org/schema/aop"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.2.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="knight" class="knights.BraveKnight">
        <constructor-arg ref="quest" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="quest" class="quests.SlayDragonQuest">
        <constructor-arg value="#(T(System).out)" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="minstrel" class="epic.Minstrel">
        <constructor-arg value="#(T(System).out" />
    </bean>

    <aop:config>
        <aop:aspect ref="minstrel">
            <aop:pointcut id="embark" expression="execution(* *.embarkOnQuest(..))" />

            <aop:before pointcut-ref="embark" method="singBeforeQuest" />

            <aop:after pointcut-ref="embark" method="singAfterQuest" />
        </aop:aspect>
    </aop:config>
</beans>
```

I'd appreciate any suggestions.
Thanks.

Comment: What is the version of Spring you are using?

Comment: You should check, if spring-aop is on the classpath. If you use Maven, execute `mvn dependency:tree` to get the list of your project dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a www to the namespace element: `xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"`